# Parse data into separate, labeled arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array of some data like this:

```
  anonymous {
    id: 1680,
    data: 
     { _ID: 0,
       JOB_ID: 1333,
       RecNum: 11832338,
       Pressure: 999.439,
       Pressure2: 714.131 },
    creationDate: 2018-05-09T14:00:23.199Z,
    job: 1 }
```

What I need to do is have each item that has pressure be put into its own array.  So in this case I would end up with two arrays, Pressure and Pressure2, with those being the labels of each array

This code here only makes one array with double the values

```
  Object.keys(this.query.rows).forEach(blob =>{
     pipelines.data.push( this.query.rows[blob].data.Pressure)
     pipelines.data.push( this.query.rows[blob].data.Pressure2)
     pipelines.creationDate.push( this.query.rows[blob].creationDate)
   })
```

I have also tried using the map function but in several attempts, I only get 'undefined' as a result.

I can get the keys of my data but how do I use this to test my data and put into the proper array?

```
 const myDataKeys = Object.keys(this.query.rows[0].data);
```

Comment: Please can you post expected output.

Comment: Kindly share the exact example for this.query.rows and it’s instance type.

Comment: There's no array in that data. Please post an example of the data you actually have, and an example of how you want the data to be structured in response. It would also be nice if you posted your attempts at using the map function as it may be that you were close there.